# How to change data block allocation algorithm in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I wrote a program in Java that allocates every node, some blocks of data according to its load (based on data blocks loaded so far).

How can I make the HDFS (in Hadoop 1.2.1) to obey my algorithm and allocate data blocks to each nodes based on this algorithm?

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: What is happing? What do you expect?

Comment: Hi Actually I want to manage data block distribution in hadoop by myself.and change the Default block distribution on every node for example Node A is to time faster than Node B and Node A's  storage space is double than node B .I want to give to node A more data block than node B. can you help me about this thanls.  with regards

Comment: Have a look at this one if it is useful for you: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-385 and https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HDFS-RAID